# Text layout relative to div

Tags: html, css

I have a box and I want to type a **h2** top of that box, which floated right. I want **h1** to be in the middle of the box and top of that (I mean center of outside of the box).

**Html**

```
<h1>News</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width: 400px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will probably be encouraged by more than one occasion to check out [/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is to help you make your questions as great as they can be. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Google **float** you get this as the first hit and get an example how to use it:  [CSS Float property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

```css
.box {
width: 400px; 
height: 200px; 
background-color: red;

}

.txt-box > .box{
display: block;
}

.txt-box {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

h1 {
margin: 0;
}

h2 {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt-box" >
<h1>News</h1>
<div class="box">
<h2>Box text</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of approaching this specific H1 tag.

html:

```
<h1 class ="news-h1">News</h1>
<div class="box"></div>
```

css:

```
.box {width: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: red;}
.news-h1 {float:right;}
```

Comment: Sorry I am Iranian and I can't talk English too good. No. I mean, in that code you typed, h1, NEWS is on the box, but It is left. I want to center it. But center of the box. Sorry again for my bad question

Comment: No problem at all. 

So you want to use the "text-align" property. 
    .news-h1 {text-align:center;}